# Parse date in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying converted from VARCHAR(50) to DATE; only date; but it did not give me any results
however this is the statement i used:

```
SELECT COUNT(F0)
FROM [OriginalData]
WHERE F1 between Convert(VARCHAR(11),'25/12/1988',103) and 
          convert(VARCHAR(11),'16/01/2013',103) AND F0 = 120002
```

The only way it shown results is when the day string is 01; e.g:

01/01/1988 and 01/01/2013

so please any advice how to converted from from string to date and compare it?

Comment: You should try to avoid having dates as strings anywhere near the database. They ought to be converted as early as possible on the input side, and as late as possible on the output side, of whatever applications you write.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `F1` is `varchar(50)`, then you are doing a string comparison.

Use proper ISO dates...

```
...
WHERE CONVERT(date, F1, 112) -- change this to match F1 format
         BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'19881225',112) and 
                 CONVERT(date,'20130116',112)
       AND F0 = 120002
```

Note that this isn't efficient from an indexing perspective because of the `CONVERT` required on `F1`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i have missing converting F1 in where statment

Comment: And what is the efficient way to do it, if you can help please?

Comment: @MohammadAbuQauod: 1. store as date or datetime 2. Use a computed column with CONVERT, add an index. Saying that, assuming (F0, F1) is indexed it may be "good enough"...

Comment: Thanks sir, first solution i can't did it, becouse there is a huge exist data, and i'll try your 2nd suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it like this

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/07/2009', 103)
```

that means query will be

```
SELECT COUNT(F0)
FROM [OriginalData]
WHERE F1 between Convert(datetime,'25/12/1988',103) and 
          convert(datetime,'16/01/2013',103) AND F0 = 120002
```

instead of `VARCHAR(11)` use  `DateTime` data type while converting

**Note** : Assuming `F1` is type of `datetime`

---

if F1 datatype of varchar than

```
SELECT COUNT(F0)
FROM [OriginalData]
WHERE Convert(datetime,F1,103) between Convert(datetime,'25/12/1988',103) and 
          convert(datetime,'16/01/2013',103) AND F0 = 120002
```

convert F1 also like in above query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '25/12/1988', 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to conver from string to date is like this:

```
CONVERT (datetime, '16.01.2013', 103)
```

and you are using `Varchar` there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query :

```
declare @t varchar(100) = '26/12/1988'

select case
        when convert(date,@t,103) between Convert(date,'25/12/1988',103) and convert(date,'16/01/2013',103) 
                then @t
        else
            'date is not in the specified range'    
        end
```